# How to get google Shared Drives Root Id

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have got my Drive Id that is shared With me .
I want to find the shared drive root ID.

```
my Drive: root

shared With me : sharedWithMe
```

Comment: What is your Java releated question?

Comment: @LutzHorn , i guess he want to know the root Id programically.

Comment: I used 'root' to get a list of My Drive folder files, use 'sharedWithMe' got a list of Shared With Me folder files, now I want to get a list of Shared Drive folder files

Comment: check this: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-shareddrives#using_client_libraries

Answer (score 1):

You can even try using Postman or SOAP UI to get the details like mentioned in this official link:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get#try-it

Hitting `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/root` in postman/soap UI will produce a JSON response , where your root will be mentioned.

Note: in above request `root` is alias of your root folder. You should get a JSON response where you should have 'id' of root folder.

If you want to know the folder structure then try below, else try above procedure.

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("Invoices");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());
```

> In the Drive API, a folder is essentially a file — one identified by
>   the special folder MIME type application/vnd.google-apps.folder. You
>   can create a new folder by inserting a file with this MIME type and a
>   folder title. Do not include an extension when setting a folder title.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder

Comment: i know 'root' is root folder alias,but i want know 'Shared Drives' alias ?